# I need to retrieve individual column from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My Sql Server database has three tables (Amount, wthdrwl, spent), each table has got id, and amount column.
I want to retrieve the amount column from these three different tables.

Comment: Can you post schema of your table so that we can see how these three table are related, however as per the names of tables there must be some key to relate entries in three tables, try using joins.

Answer (score 5):

For both MySQL, SQL-Server, use `UNION` (implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Amount FROM Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM wthdrwl
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM spent
```

Comment: Thanx for the instant reply, but i am getting all in a single column, I need seperate columns for amount.

Comment: @AShrinivasRao - Do you mean getting them from the three tables like `Amount1 | SpentAmount | wthdrwlAmount`? in this case is there any relation between the three tables?

Comment: Yes Primary key is there

Comment: @AShrinivasRao - I mean between the three tables, is there any relations between them?

Comment: @AShrinivasRao - Please edit your question and show me the tables' structures and by which columns they are related.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there is some relation between three tables

```
SELECT  A.Amount AS Amount ,
        W.Amount AS Withdrawal ,
        S.Amount AS Spent
FROM    Amount A
         LEFT OUTER JOIN wthdrwl W ON A.ID = W.ID
     LEFT JOIN spent S ON A.ID = S.ID
```

Check here- [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f3f7/2)

Comment: @RajeshPaul His question doesn't makes any sense if there is no relation between those tables and as per name of his tables, i can say those ID column must be the relation between tables, Amount , Withdrawl , spent, It clicks he need to show a user details or what else he needs query ? So !

Comment: @RajeshPaul, you are joining (cross joining)... you just don't know it yet.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You may want to do a full outer join? What if there's a value in Spent and not in Amount.  Those would get lost in a left join.

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact. This has to be so.

Comment: @samyi Yes i also thought of full join but then i thought, If a person do not have amount how can he withdraw or spent, however it's a wild though and may not be applicable, but i still support it should be full join.

Comment: @Suraj I don't think It should be left join we should use Inner join or "Join" not the Left outer join.Please read this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/ first and then apply join.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar Please explain why should we use inner join, I get the article but please explain for this situation why inner-join not `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Suraj that you should understand:Let's stay he want only relating table.In your sql fiddle let's say both table have id 1,2,3 and all are exist in the 3 tables.so use inner join or join.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar Considering the scenario `Table1` has all three fields but if `Table2 ` and `Table3` are missing any column in that case `Inner Join` will not bring desired result .

Comment: @Suraj I agree in that scenario "left join" used but according to your example there is no use of "Left outer Join" in that scenario we have to use "Inner join".

Comment: @VaibhavParmar In that case you should not directly read my answer and find an excuse to downvote me but rather understand the questions read comments, what OP wants and then come to answers.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar Just go up in comment section and read `sam yi` comment .

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment above, use a fixed string to indicate which table the values came from:

```
SELECT 'Amount' AS source, Amount FROM Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 'whtdrwl' AS source, Amount FROM whtdrwl
UNION ALL
SELECT 'spent' AS source, Amount FROM spent
```

then you can easily identify the rows. You could write a query that does this as a single row with 3 columns, but it's far easier doing it this way.

Comment: It helped me , but still not satisfied. I need Amount as different columns from Amount, whtdrwl and spent

Comment: Yes, and? That's what this query does. it runs 3 separate queries to get the `Amount` field from your three tables, and then returns them as individual rows, one row per record per table.

Comment: can't it be the other way round, getting seperate columns

Comment: You have no fixed relationships between the tables, or at least haven't bothered telling us what the relationships are, so don't complain when the best possible answers don't conform to your expectations. If you don't give us all the details, we can't give you the "best" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query-

```
select amount.amount, wthdrwl.amount, spent.amount from amount, wthdrwl, spent where amount.amount=wthdrwl.amount and wthdrwl.amount=spent.amount;
```

Here you have to **use the table name along with the attribute** to distinctly identify the `amount` attribute from 3 different table. You need to **check for the equality** of the `id` attribute in all 3 tables **to correspond to a particular entity** in a row of the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put them all on one line then you have to have a way to link the columns together via a 2nd column, for example a txnId column that occurs in each of the 3 tables.  Then you could do something like:

```
SELECT Amount.Amount Amt, whtdrwl.Amount Wdrl, spent.Amount Spd 
FROM Amount, whthdrwl, spent
WHERE Amount.txnId=wthdrwl.txnId
    Amount.txnId=spent.txnId
```